# python ttk.Entry how to center the input

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

[image: screenshot of my app]

Here is a screenshot of a program I am writing using Python Tkinter. I use `ttk.Entry` widget to get the user input.

I would like to know how to **center** the input in the `Entry` (as you can see, the input is now stuck to the **left** part of the widget)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Entry widgets take the option `justify`, which for centered text should be `'center'`. When creating the widget, do something like

```
e = ttk.Entry(master, ..., justify='center')
```